# Converting vector<float> to GLfloat

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Im currently working with OpenGL in iOS and i would like to hear if theres any way of converting a vector to GLfloat?

Since glBufferData:

```
void glBufferData(GLenum  target,
    GLsizeiptr      size,
    const GLvoid *  data,
    GLenum      usage);
```

The vector is a part of the stl_bvector.h

Comment: Ehm, `GLfloat` is just a single floating point value. Do you mean to ask how you can pass your vector of floats into the data argument of `glBufferData`? i.e. something along the lines of `glBufferDataARB( whatever_target, floatvector.size()*sizeof(float), &(floatvector[0]), whatever_usage);`

Comment: Exactly what i need. But why do you define floatvector[0]? Would that not only choose the first value?

Comment: Yes, that's what you want. And the `&` in front of it ensure you get the address of the first element. Which is the address you want to use.

Comment: I dont understand quite. It will not take the entire vector as input?

Comment: Sure it will. You have to give it a pointer to the data (which is the address of the first element in the vector). And the size argument ensures it will read the full extent of it (all bytes contained).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
void glppBufferData(GLenum target, std::vector<T> const &data, GLenum usage)
{
    glBufferDate( target, 
                  sizeof(data[0]) * data.size(), 
                  reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(&data[0]), 
                  usage);
}
```